# Magento 2 customer logged in checking - in \Magento\Customer\Model\Session method isLoggedIn() always returns false

Tags: magento2, login, customer-session

I am instantiating the customer session helper (`\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession`) correctly, but this function always returns false, even though the customer is logged in. What am I missing here?

Comment: Give us your code

Comment: Have you try below answer code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `cacheable=false` for that block, in the layout *.xml* file.

Comment: Sadly now your page will not be cached by Full Page Cache -- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html

Comment: Not recommended. This will forbid caching of your whole page.

Comment: @Vladimir this is not recommended at all. Need to understand the architecture of Magento 2

Answer (score 8):

If store cache is enable, you can not get customer session. Check below code for get customer session with enable cache.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 */
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    ) 
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCustomerId(){
    $customer = $this->_customerSession->create();
    var_dump($customer->getCustomer()->getId());
}
```

Write above code in block, It is working even cache is enable.

Comment: Great, saved my day.

Comment: This is the right answer ! FPC caches the Customer Session object as well. So we need to create a fresh one using SessionFactory while FPC is enabled. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution will work. Haha my english is a bit poor so my explanation is not good. You can check out the materials here : https://aureatelabs.com/blog/how-to-check-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-when-a-cache-is-enabled-in-magento-2/

```
namespace SnaptecHue\Customer\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class CustomerCustomInfo extends Template
{
    protected $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomerIsLoggedIn()
    {
        return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }

    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue('customer_id');
    }

    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue('customer_name');
    }

    public function getCustomerEmail()
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue('customer_email');
    }
}
namespace SnaptecHue\Customer\Plugin;

class CustomerSessionContext
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
    */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
    */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject
    * @param callable $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function aroundDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            'customer_id',
            $this->customerSession->getCustomerId(),
            false
        );

        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            'customer_name',
            $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getName(),
            false
        );

        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            'customer_email',
            $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail(),
            false
        );

        return $proceed($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
protected $_session;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_session = $session;
    ...
}

public function isLoggedIn()
{
       if ($this->_session->isLoggedIn()) {
              // Customer is logged in 
        } else {
           // Customer is not logged in
        }
}
```

Note: This works for frontend customers only. So If you are checking in admin section then it won't work.

Thanks.